# Iterate though all possible floating-point values, starting from lowest

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, numeric, floating-accuracy

I am writing a unit test for a math function and I would like to be able to "walk" all possible floats/doubles.

Due to IEEE shenanigans, floating types cannot be incremented (`++`) at their extremities. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152536/long-double-increment-operator-not-working-on-large-numbers) for more details. That answer states :

> one can only add multiples of 2^(n-N)

But never mentions what little `n` is.

A solution to iterate all possible values from +0.0 to +infinity is given in this great [blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/). The technique involves using a union with an `int` to walk the different values of a `float`. This works due to the following properties explained in the post, though they are only valid for positive numbers.

> 1. Adjacent floats have adjacent integer representations
> 2. Incrementing the integer representation of a float moves to the next representable float, moving away from zero

His solution for +0.0 to +infinity (`0.f` to `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`) :

```
union Float_t {
    int32_t RawExponent() const { return (i >> 23) & 0xFF; }
    int32_t i;
    float f;
};

Float_t allFloats;
allFloats.f = 0.0f;
while (allFloats.RawExponent() < 255) {
    allFloats.i += 1;
}
```

Is there a solution for -infinity to +0.0 (`std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()` to `0.f`)?

I've tested [`std::nextafter` and `std::nexttoward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) and couldn't get them to work. Maybe this is an MSVC issue?

I would be ok with any sort of hack since this is a unit test. Thanks!

Comment: `nextafter` is the standard high-level way to do exactly what you want. What does not work about it?

Comment: @PascalCuoq It doesn't increment the value. I will add an example of what I am doing, 1 sec.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are right, nextafter works... I guess I have a bug elsewhere. Thank you! Feel free to make your comment an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Even if you could iterate through all 64-bit double values, your program would not complete within your lifetime.

Comment: Better get started! XD I guess I'll write a random fuzzer instead. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal Cuoq correctly points out `std::nextafter` is the right solution. I had a problem elsewhere in my code. Sorry for the unnecessary question.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

float i = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
float hi = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
float new_i = std::nextafterf(i, hi);
assert(i != new_i);

double d = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
double hi_d = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double new_d = std::nextafter(d, hi_d);
assert(d != new_d);

long double ld = std::numeric_limits<long double>::lowest();
long double hi_ld = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max();
long double new_ld = std::nextafterl(ld, hi_ld);
assert(ld != new_ld);


for (float d = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
        d < std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
        d = std::nextafterf(
                d, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())) {
    // Wait a lifetime?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can walk all 32-bit bit representations by using all values of a 32-bit `unsigned int`. Then you will walk really *all* representations, positive and negative, including both nulls (there are two) and also all the *not a number* representations (NaN). You may or may not want to filter out the NaN representations, or just filter out the signaling ones and leave the non signaling ones in. This depends on your use case.

Example:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0;;)
{
    float f;
    // Type punning: Force the bit representation of i into f.
    // Type punning is hard because mostly undefined in C/C++. 
    // Using memcpy() usually avoids any type punning warning.
    memcpy(&f, &i, sizeof(f));

    // Use f here.
    // Warning: Using signaling NaNs may throw exceptions or raise signals.

    i++;
    if (i == 0)
        break;
}
```

Instead you can also walk a 32-bit `int` from -2**31 to +(2**31-1). This makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through all the `float` values can be done with simple understanding of the floating-point representation:

- The distance between consecutive subnormal values is the minimum normal times the “epsilon”. Simply iterate through all the subnormals using this distance as an increment.
- The distance between the normal values at the lowest exponent is the same. Step through them with the same increment.
- For each exponent, the distance increases according to the floating-point radix. Simply multiply the increment by the radix and step through all the values for the next exponent.
- Repeat until infinity is reached.

Observe that the inner loop in the code below is simply:

```
for (; x < Limit; x += Increment)
    Test(x);
```

This has the advantage that only normal floating-point arithmetic is used. The inner loop contains only one addition and one comparison (plus any tests you want to perform with each number). No library functions are called in the loop, no representations are dissected or copied to general registers or otherwise manipulated. There is nothing to impede performance.

This code steps through only the non-negative numbers. The negative numbers can be tested separately in the same way or can share this code by inserting a call `Test(-x)`.

```
#include <limits>


static void Test(float x)
{
    //  Insert unit test for value x here.
}


int main(void)
{
    typedef float T;

    static const int Radix = std::numeric_limits<T>::radix;
    static const T Infinity = std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();

    /*  Increment is the current distance between floating-point numbers.  We
        start it at distance between subnormal numbers.
    */
    T Increment =
        std::numeric_limits<T>::min() * std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();

    /*  Limit is the next boundary where the distance between floating-point
        numbers changes.  We will increment up to that limit and then adjust
        the limit and increment.  We start it at the top of the first set of
        normals, which allows the first loop to increment first through the
        subnormals and then through the normals with the lowest exponent.
        (These two sets have the same step size between adjacent values.)
    */
    T Limit = std::numeric_limits<T>::min() * Radix;

    /*  Start with zero and continue until we reach infinity.
        We execute an inner loop that iterates through all the significands of
        one floating-point exponent.  Each time it completes, we step up the
        limit and increment.
    */
    for (T x = 0; x < Infinity; Limit *= Radix, Increment *= Radix)

        //  Increment x through all the significands with the current exponent.
        for (; x < Limit; x += Increment)

            //  Test with the current value of x.
            Test(x);

    //  Also test infinity.
    Test(Infinity);
}
```

(This code assumes the floating-point type has subnormals, and that they are not flushed to zero. The code can be readily adjusted to support these alternatives as well.)

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Thanks for taking the time to document all the details, but the solution only works for 0 to +infinity, not -infinity to +infinity.